# ViewBinding with Java11, AndroidStudio always shows error (but runs without any problem)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewbinding

I notice that with Java8 there is no problem with viewBinding in AndroidStudio (Arctic Fox).

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

However, once I set `compileOptions` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_11`, AndroidStudio always falsely shows viewBiding(s) errors though it can compile and run with no problem.

I tested this with a fresh new project in AndroidStudio ArcticFox. It suggests to import the class. After imported, it says *Package not found*:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Is this AndroidStudio's bug, or are there any misconfiguration about Java compiler setting in my AndroidStudio?

All I did something particular was `JavaVersion.VERSION_11`.

Comment: Maybe you need to update the Gradle plugin. Faced such kinds of issues due to Gradle plugin on lower AS

Comment: @Sachin I think Gradle plugin is recent: `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"`

Comment: Still happening today -.-

The project can be built and launched on a physical device but it show the annoying red message.

Comment: This bug is not fixed yet with Patch 4 (Gradle 7.0.4).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As google's support answered: This issue has been fixed and landed in BB canary 8. It is specific to Java 11.

Comment: Thank you. FYI, I searched about Bumblebee canary then I found this issue tracker: [View Binding not working with Java 11](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180946610?pli=1). I'll wait next stable update.

Comment: With stable Bumblebee the problem has actually been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

remove the import line from your project and import it again by pressing Alt+Enter then inform  me

```
import com.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   

ActivityMainBinding binding;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

}

}
```

Comment: I imported the class again. But the imported class definition is red colored `Package not found` error.

Comment: make sure your package name is correct in class definatination??? otherwise viewBinding is right

Comment: It does not solve the problem of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I did the following:

- Run the gradle updater

  **OR**
- open the terminal and run `gradlew help --scan`, it will generate a report that tells will what you should edit before migrate to `Gradle 7.0`
- open your `gradle.properties` and `distributionUrl` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip`
- Go to your `Project build.gradle` and set the classpath to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0`.
- Sync with Gradle FIles and rebuild your project.

Comment: Thank you for your information. My test project is a newly created project and it uses Gradle 7.0 (gradle-wrapper.properties: gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip) from its creation.